# When segue is performing throws unrecognized selector sent to instance error message showed?

Tags: ios7, segue

I've been looking for a solution since yesterday, and i still can't figure out actual problem.
My app has been worked for 2 months on ios8 devices. I also set it up for ios7 devices, but I didn't know it was crashing on ios7 devices because of segue.

**This is prepareSegue function:**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if (segue.identifier == "navigateToSettingsView") {
        if let settingsView = segue.destinationViewController as? SettingControllerView
        {
            settingsView.isSetup = self.isSetup
        }
    }
}
```

My segue style is present modally and current context.

**I have navigate function to perform segue like this:**

```
  func navigateToSettings() {
    // call setting view for adjusting settings
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("navigateToSettingsView", sender: self)
    })
}
```

I'm still tracing debug now, it's getting me annoyed so much. And in the debugger log area. The only prompt is 'containsString:' and unrecognized selector sent to instance. I know unrecognized selector issue, sorry for that. But my problem has no reason on debug log.Also, i can't use allocations instruments because of ios7.Eventhough, I'm not using any String contains function. I know the issue rangeOfString :S

```
[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into this issue as well, however my problem is in iOS 6.1 so it may be different. I didn't try to re-produce the issue in iOS 7 yet.

What I discovered was a newly added UITextField on my storyboard caused the crash. Removing the UITextField fixed the problem.

You may want to remove some recent UI elements from your storyboard and see if that helps. I found copying an existing UITextField and pasting it where I wanted the new one still allowed my app to run on iOS 6.1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've solved already ;) the reason was auto resizing issue with my custom placeholder text view. When the app tried to realign the constraints, it threw that error. Anyway, I solved it with deeper debugging. After that, I've become adding items programmatically not in interface builder. Thanks again.